# Firebase in React Native application using redux

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

can we use more than one firebase.database.ref(path) in one react native application that uses redux ? thanks

```
elementsRef_1 = firebaseApp.database().ref(path_1)
elementsRef_2= firebaseApp.database().ref(path_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Firebase is built for you to use a lot of refs and listen and write to a lot of different nodes in your db.

Comment: Hi, Thank you .. can you please provide some example

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for? You can just use firebase as recommended and demonstrated in their tutorials.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup